# Creating and importing private package of hand-written type definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsconfig, type-definition

I need to create a private npm package containing (only) custom type definitions (typedefs). These are hand-written d.ts files that were not generated by TypeScript. As these are proprietary, I can't add them to DefinitelyTyped.

Folder structure: typings / mymodule / index.d.ts
index.d.ts contains: `declare module mymodule { ... }`

The package preserves the structure, so after installing in another project I have:
node_modules / @mycompany / mytypes / typings / mymodule / index.d.ts

Unfortunately now I have to edit tsconfig.json in the other project to add:

```
    "include": [
      "node_modules/@mycompany/mytypes/typings"
    ],
```

or optionally (and more correctly?) add under `compilerOptions`:

```
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "node_modules/@mycompany/mytypes/typings"
      ]
```

After that, it works - I can reference `mymodule.SomeType` in the other project.

Is there a way I can make this work automatically on npm install without having to edit tsconfig includes (that is, have it behave like a DefinitelyTyped package)?

If there is a more correct way to do this, that's a valid answer.

I'm using TypeScript 3.6 or 3.7, depending on the importing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make this work automatically on npm install without having to edit tsconfig includes

The *only* way to make this work *without any* changes to tsconfig.json is if the typings are shipped as a part of the module you are trying to use.

E.g. this shipping as a part of module will occur automatically if you [write your package in TypeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJNIuBTAb6Q).

Comment: Could you clarify please? All packages are TypeScript. Essentially I am trying to share common interfaces and types with multiple TypeScript projects.

Comment: I tried creating a package based on your excellent video. I ended up with lib / index.d.ts with the interfaces and types plus a very simple index.js. How does TypeScript know to auto-include those types on import?